# find all pair of grandfather relationships using prolog

Tags: prolog

If you have these facts:

```
parent(albert, bob).
parent(albert, betsy).
parent(albert, bill).
parent(alice, bob).
parent(alice, betsy).
parent(alice, bill).
parent(bob, carl).
parent(bob, charlie).
```

And then this code:

```
grand_parent(X, Y) :-
    parent(Z, X),
    parent(Y, Z).
```

How to write a query to find all pairs that share
grand-parenthood relationship?

Comment: If the facts `parent(albert, bob)` and `parent(bob, carl)` are both true, then we can conclude that `grand_parent(albert, carl)` is also true. So, to be consistent, I think the predicate `grand_parent/2` should be defined as `grand_parent(X, Z) :- parent(X, Y), parent(Y, Z).`.

Answer (score 0):

A basic query would look like this:

```
?- grand_parent(X,Y).
```

giving the following output (after one answer `;` will show the next one):

```
X = carl,
Y = albert;

X = carl,
Y = alice;

X = charlie,
Y = albert;

X = charlie,
Y = alice;

false.
```

However if you want to have all grandchildren of a specific person, you can either programm your own  "find_all_grandchilren"-predicate or just use an inbuild predicate for collecting all answers. Example:

```
?- findall(Y,grand_parent(carl,Y),X).
X = [albert, alice].
```

Which reads as: find every term `Y` which satisfies `grand_parent(carl,Y)` and put it in the list `X`.

Tested with SWISH.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data model right is important.

You might find it useful to change your data model up to better represent the real-world model. Something like

```
parents( carol, bob, jim ).
```

Which is to say, `carol` and `bob` are respectively, `jim`'s mother and father.

Once you have that things fall into place:

```
mother(M,C) :- parents(M,_,C).

father(F,C) :- parents(_,F,C).

child(P,C) :- mother(P,C).
child(P,C) :- father(P,C).

child(M,F,C) :- parents(M,F,C).

children(P,Cs) :- findall( C , child(P,C), Cs).

children(M,F,Cs) :- findall( C, child(M,F,C), Cs).

family(M,F,[M,F|Cs]) :- children(M,F,Cs).

sibling(S,C) :- parents(M,F,C), parents(M,F,S).

grandparents(GM,GF,C) :- mother(M,C), parents(GM,GF,M).
grandparents(GM,GF,C) :- father(F,C), parents(GM,GF,F).
```

Now, to get the list of all grandparent pairs is trivial:

```
all_grandparents(GPs) :- findall( GM:GF, grandparents(GM,GF,_), GPs ).
```